# How do you send or transfer an NFT to another account on NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

The goal is to send another user's account the NFT from an account I control.  The NFT follows the standard, but it appears that wallets do not support this feature in their UIs now so we have to execute a shell command to effect the transfer.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract adheres to the [NEP-171](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html) standard, then you can use the [near-cli](https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli) and call `nft_transfer`. You also need to use the mainnet, and login to the wallet. Caller of the method must attach a deposit of 1 yoctoNear for security purposes ([see requirements for more details](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core#nft-interface))

```
export NEAR_ENV=mainnet
near login
near call contractName nft_transfer '{"receiver_id": "someNearAccount", "token_id": "someTokenId"}' --accountId yourAccountId --depositYocto 1
```

Now, if the call returns without any errors, the NFT should have been transferred. In the terminal, you also get a link to the explorer to see the transaction.
You can also call another method `nft_token`, to see the updated information:

```
near view contractName nft_token '{"tokenId": "someTokenId"}'
```

You'll see that the owner_id has changed.

Comment: It's pretty buried out there, but you need to attach 1 yoctoNEAR as a deposit or you get an error saying "Requires attached deposit of exactly 1 yoctoNEAR".  To do this, append `--depositYocto 1` and it should work fine.

Protip: you can dig for the token ID in the explorer transaction for the confirm used to originally get the NFT. May require using a Base64 decoder (google one).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn’t aware of the 1 yoctoNear requirement for a transfer. I didn’t need it for testnet when I was debugging. Maybe I missed something. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: After reading the NEP-171 standard again, attaching 1 YoctoNear deposit is required for security purposes. When I was testing in testnet, I used my own NFT contract, which doesn't have this implemented. I guess I need to add it in. Thanks again for the comment.